# How to run dat-node as a micro service?

Tags: node.js, vercel, dat-protocol, vercel-micro

**UPDATE:** Added the full server code. Notice that the route for static content is working fine, only the one relative to Dat fails. Also, I'm running node `10.8.0` with no transpiler or anything, server is ran with `micro -l tcp://0.0.0.0:$PORT`

---

I'm trying to run `dat-node` with Zeit `micro`. I have this micro service

```
const { send } = require('micro')
const Dat = require('dat-node')
const handler = require('serve-handler')
const { router, get, post } = require('microrouter')

const static = async (request, response) => {
  await handler(request, response, {
  // static app folder
  public: 'static',
    // javascript header for es modules
    headers: {
      source: '**/*.mjs',
      headers: [{
        key: 'Content-Type',
        value: 'text/javascript'
      }]
    },
    // no directory listing
    directoryListing: false
  })
}

const createGame = (request, response) => {
  Dat('./game', (err, dat) => {
    if (err) throw err

    let progress = dat.importFiles({watch: true})

    progress.on('put', function (src, dest) {
      console.log('Importing ', src.name, ' into archive')
    })

    dat.joinNetwork()

    send(response, 200, { key: dat.key.toString('hex') })
  })
}

const joinGame = (request, response) => {

}

module.exports = router(
  post('/game', createGame),
  post('/game/:game', joinGame),
  get('/*', static)
)
```

I just want to create a dat archive and return the public key, but when I call `send` I get this error

```
(node:2054) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:469:11)
    at send (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/micro/lib/index.js:72:8)
    at Dat (/home/ubuntu/workspace/index.js:35:5)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/dat-node/index.js:112:9
    at apply (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/thunky/index.js:44:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)(node:2054) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)(node:2054) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

So, I'm not sure where the header is being sent, maybe I'm just handling Dat callback in a wrong way? not sure how to implement this service.

Comment: Does it work if you just send an empty response (without the key)? Or maybe if you remove the `async` in the callback, it may not be necessary with the code you have.

Comment: @joehand If I remove the `async` keyword, I get the same error, but this time the server process is killed, with the snippet as is, the exception is logged, but the server keeps running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be the usage of `micro`, not any issue with `dat-node`. When you are doing async work in micro, you need to use the `async/await` tools of Javascript (promises).

Here is the fixed code:

```js
const createGame = async (request, response) => {
  var key = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    Dat('./game', (err, dat) => {
      if (err) throw err

      let progress = dat.importFiles({watch: true})

      progress.on('put', function (src, dest) {
        console.log('Importing ', src.name, ' into archive')
      })

      dat.joinNetwork()
      resolve(dat.key.toString('hex'))
    })
  })
  console.log('sending')
  send(response, 200, { key })
}
```

Comment: Totally right. I used node promisify function to write `const dat = await Dat('./game')`, which is actually the same as you wrote. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The snippet works if you export the function. Run with `micro whatever.js` and curl to localhost:3000 which should return the key.

```
const { send } = require('micro')
const Dat = require('dat-node')

module.exports = (request, response) => {
  Dat('./game', async (err, dat) => {
    if (err) throw err

    let progress = dat.importFiles({watch: true})

    progress.on('put', function (src, dest) {
      console.log('Importing ', src.name, ' into archive')
    })

    dat.joinNetwork()

    send(response, 200, { key: dat.key.toString('hex') })
 })
}
```

Comment: I'm actually exporting. I will update my question with the whole code of the server.